# How to convert umlauts in a C char array to hex codes?

Tags: arrays, c, char, ascii, diacritics

My task is to convert a char array containing multiple umlauts into a char array with the corresponging ANSI hex codes to correctly display it in the terminal.

ASCII ANSI

- 'Ä' 0x8E
- 'ä' 0x84
- 'Ö' 0x99
- 'ö' 0x94
- 'Ü' 0x9A
- 'ü' 0x81
- 'ß' 0xE1

My try looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char lied[] = "ÄäÖöÜüß\r\n";  // this syntax must remain the same


    cout << lied << endl;

    for (char* p = lied; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        char c;
        switch (*p)
        {
        case 'Ä': c = '\x8e'; break;
        case 'ä': c = '\x84'; break;
        case 'Ö': c = '\x99'; break;
        case 'ö': c = '\x94'; break;
        case 'Ü': c = '\x9a'; break;
        case 'ü': c = '\x81'; break;
        case 'ß': c = '\xe1'; break;
        default:
            c = *p;
            break;
        }

        *p = c;
    }
    
    cout << lied << endl;
}
```

Obviously my solution doesn't work as I found out that the chars can't be compared in this way. It seems that each umlaut consists of 2 chars in the array (which both have negative values). If I'm right the umlauts need to be interpreted as unsigned chars as they require more memory to represent additional symbols.
How can this be done using C style char arrays and pointers?

*(I'm only allowed to use basic C except the C++ input/output streams)*

Can I even simply overwrite the umlauts or should I output the characters directly when looping and replace them if necessary? *I prefer to try the first method first.*

Comment: That's not so much a problem of C but a problem of encoding. The umlauts don't really have ASCII codes. Today, they are likely encoded with Unicode, perhaps as single chars in ISO-8859-1 or as two chars in UTF-8, in which case `strlen(lied) == 16`.

Comment: Why don't you print out the hex value of `(unsigned char) *p` as you iterate and see for yourself how `lied` is encoded? Then use that data to implement your replacement.

Comment: @MOehm Sorry to ask this, but how can I replace the characters now? I am aware that it is not a C "problem". But I must create a char array with escape hex characters and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: can you use wchar_t? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/

Comment: Oh! That's what you want to do. In C, `'\x8e'` is only a single character. You want to replace that with the multi-char sequence `"\\x8e"`. You should create a new character array and be aware that in the worst case, each character can be expanded to four chars, so make room for that.

Comment: @MOehm I don't know if I understood you correctly. I can still loop over the array with pointers and take each char and put it into a new array and use the multi-char sequence "\\x8e" if necessary? My problem is still the switch, where the individual cases do not come into operation at all. How can I first recognize the special characters correctly? Until now I get for the special characters first -61 and then another negative number. But the char values of the cases have other values.

Comment: The problem is that it is not quite clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to turn a string with umlauts into an escaped C string? Then look at my answer. Do you want to turn a string with umlauts in your compiler's locale into a string that you can print in an old DOS environment? Then look at Serge's answer. You also haven't addressed the points some people have asked in comments. For example if an Ä is represented by two chars, your `switch` won't fire.

Comment: @MOehm Thank you very much for your effort. Sorry that I have not formulated my question precisely enough... As a beginner, I just didn't know how to ask it in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really friendly, because it does not directly give what is important. I could guess most from details:

Your *ASCII ANSI* table shows that you want a Window codepage 850 encoding for the following characters `ÄäÖöÜüß`

*It seems that each umlaut consists of 2 chars in the array (which both have negative values)*: that means that your source file is currently UTF-8 encoded.

So here is the translation table that you need:

```
 char      utf-8   cp850
    Ä  "\xc3\x84"  "\x8e"
    ä  "\xc3\xa4"  "\x84"
    Ö  "\xc3\x96"  "\x99"
    ö  "\xc3\xb6"  "\x94"
    Ü  "\xc3\x9c"  "\x9a"
    ü  "\xc3\xbc"  "\x81"
    ß  "\xc3\x9f"  "\xe1"
```

I changed your code to:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char lied[] = "ÄäÖöÜüß\r\n";  // this syntax must remain the same


    cout << lied << endl;

    int second = 0;

    char *q = lied;
    for (char* p = lied; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        if (*p == '\xc3') {
            second = 1;
        }
        else if (second) {
            char c;
            second = 0;
            switch (*p)
            {
            case '\x84': c = '\x8e'; break;
            case '\xa4': c = '\x84'; break;
            case '\x96': c = '\x99'; break;
            case '\xb6': c = '\x94'; break;
            case '\x9c': c = '\x9a'; break;
            case '\xbc': c = '\x81'; break;
            case '\x9f': c = '\xe1'; break;
            default:
                c = *p;
                break;
            }
            *q++ = c;
        }
        else {
            *q++ = *p;
        }
    }
    *q = 0;

    cout << lied << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In a CP850 console on my Windows system, I got as expected:

```
├ä├ñ├û├Â├£├╝├ƒ

ÄäÖöÜüß
```

Comment: I couldn't work out how to add other codes to this list. In the end, I added the new characters to a .txt file and opened it in a hex editor to see what it did. That worked. Bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you say "I want to convert umlauts into hex codes", you mean that you want a C string representation of the string, where some characters are encodes as escape sequences.

Let's do that and treat the following characters:

- basic escape sequences: The special characters like tab (`\t`) are encoded as backslash plus one letter.
- hex escape characters: All other characters not in the valid ASCII range from 32 to 127 are encoded as a sequence like `\xc0`.

These escapes make the string longer, so you cannot encode the string in place. Create another string that can hold at least four times the original string length plus one for the null terminator.

Now iterate over the original string and convert as you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char lied[] = "\"Fix Schwyz!\" quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß.\r\n";
    char encoded[4 * sizeof(lied)];
    
    const char *p = lied;
    char *q = encoded;
    
    while (*p) {
        unsigned char c = *p++;
        
        switch (c) {
        case '"':   *q++ = '\\'; *q++ = '"'; break;
        case '\r':  *q++ = '\\'; *q++ = 'r'; break;
        case '\n':  *q++ = '\\'; *q++ = 'n'; break;
        case '\t':  *q++ = '\\'; *q++ = 't'; break;
        case '\a':  *q++ = '\\'; *q++ = 'a'; break;
        case '\b':  *q++ = '\\'; *q++ = 'b'; break;
        
        default:    if (c < 32 || c > 127) {
                        static const char *hex = "0123456789abcdef";
        
                        *q++ = '\\';
                        *q++ = 'x';
                        *q++ = hex[c / 16];
                        *q++ = hex[c % 16];
                    } else {
                        *q++ = c;
                    }
        }
    }
    
    *q = '\0';
    
    puts(encoded);
    
    return 0;
}
```

In a locale with Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding, this will print:

```
\"Fix Schwyz!\" qu\xe4kt J\xfcrgen bl\xf6d vom Pa\xdf.\r\n
```

In a UTF-8 locale, you should see hwo escaped hex codes per non-ASCII character.

Things to note:

- For this solution, you don't need to know the exact codes of the umlauts, they are just "non-ASCII", just as other accented or foreign characters.
- This solution does not care about the encoding as long as it is given a string of chars.
- Your original code is C++, so instead of doing the fiddly allocation calculation yourself, you can create a `std::string` and append to it.